# Regex to match any string that keeps the order in a sequence even if it's not complete

Tags: python, c++, regex

I wonder if it's possible to create a regex that matches any string that keeps the order of the sequence in the pattern, but doesn't need to have all the characters.

Example:
pattern: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

"acfpquyz" matches the pattern because all letters are in the same order as in the pattern.

"bmu" also matches the pattern.

but "afdsz" doesn't match because "f" has to be after "d" according to the order in the pattern.

The real problem is to find a sequence of numbers in a large vector, the sequence can be incomplete but the numbers have to be in the right order. I was wondering if I could translate the problem to a search in a string using regular expressions or something else.

The answer can be C++ or python

Thanks!

Comment: You should include a tag specifying the language or programming tool that you are using along with "regex".

Comment: Quite sure this has been asked at least once before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `?` after each character does what you want:

```
regex(str, 'a?b?c?d?. . . ')
```

(The `. . .` isn't part of the string.  It is just notation to indication that you continue following the same patter of character/question mark.)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer sounds like what you want, but if for some reason you want to do the *opposite*, you would use:

```
a.*c.*f.*p.*q.*u.*y.*z
```

which is a regex that will accept `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`